# Historic derivation of Wien's law

Tags: thermodynamics, history, thermal-radiation

Every book I've read, including a lot of websites, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien%27s_displacement_law), etc, say that Wien derived this:

$$\rho_\nu(T)=\rho(\nu,T)=\nu^3f\left(\frac{\nu}{T}\right)$$

Being $\rho_v(T)$ the spectral enegy density of a black body for a given temperature and electromagnetic wave frequency. And everywhere it's mentioned that he proved this using thermodynamical arguments in a paper from 1893. I haven't been able to find that paper or that thermodynamical argument, which is what I'm interested in. I've been looking for a few days already.

Does anybody know how he did this?

Comment: See http://webpages.uidaho.edu/~crepeau/ht2009-88060.pdf, which claims that the distribution law was derived by Wien in http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/14786449708620983

Comment: @joshphysics: Those look strong. To avoid link-only answers, could you fill in the argument as an answer?

Comment: (That 1901 picture of Planck is priceless, by the way. A far shout from the usual "statesman of science" pictures.)

Comment: @joshphysics Thanks. That article was very interesting. I will try to find that article for free... maybe my university has some copies. Although that article is from year 97, will all sources say that relation was derived in his 93 paper: Eine neue Beziehung der Strahlung 
schwarzer Körper zum zweiten Hauptsatz der Wärmetheorie, which is also cited in that article, and that sadly it seems like it has no translated version.

Comment: http://www.bu.edu/simulation/publications/dcole/PDF/thermo.pdf this explains the generalized, and more useful, version of wien's law.

Comment: The 1893 paper by Willy Wien appeared in Sitzungber. preuß. Akad. Wiss. Berlin, 55 (1893). It was presented by Helmholtz at meeting of the Academy on February 9, 1893. I have a translation to Russian in the book "Von Kirchhoff bis Planck" by Hans-Georg Schöpf. If you are interested I can find it and post a summary.

Comment: @LeosOndra I would appreciate it, I don't spek any russian though. I'm not interested in the whole article, only in the derivation of that law.

Comment: @MyUserIsThis Ok, I will try to post here a summary as soon as possible (in English, of course).

Comment: @LeosOndra Thank you very much for you help and your time

Answer (score 3):

### Link to original version (German)

Willy Wien: *Über die Energievertheilung im Emissionsspectrum eines schwarzen Körpers.* Annalen der Physik, Band 294, Nr. 8, S. 662–669 (1896)

http://myweb.rz.uni-augsburg.de/~eckern/adp/history/historic-papers/1896_294_662-669.pdf

### Today's derivation

1. We calculate the eigenmodes of a box, where the mode index is $j^2 = j_x^2+j_y^2+j_z^2=\left(\frac{2\nu}{c}L\right)^2$ where we used the condition of resonance.
2. We calculate the number of modes $G(\nu)=2\frac{1}{8}\frac{4\pi}{3}j^3$ in the frequency spectrum between 0 and \nu.
3. We calculate the spectral mode density $g(\nu)=\frac{\partial G(\nu)}{\partial\nu}$. The spectral energy density $u(\nu)$ is now the product of $g(\nu)$ and the energy per mode $\epsilon_{Wien}=h\nu e^{-\frac{h\nu}{k_B T}}$ (from classical Boltzmann statistics) per volume $L^3$.
4. The rest (simple math) is up to you or check the German reference [1](http://qudev.phys.ethz.ch/content/science/BuchPhysikIV/PhysikIV2.html#QQ2-29-106). You get the relation from above and $$u(\nu)=\rho(\nu)e^{-\frac{h\nu}{k_B T}}\;.$$

Comment: The claim "the energy per mode is$\epsilon=h\nu\exp(-h\nu/kT)$" is much stronger than anything you've assumed and it is essentially equivalent to Planck's energy quantization condition. As such it would have been unknown to Wien, for whom the equipartition theorem would have governed this.

Comment: My derivation is a different than the traditional. I thought you are interested in actual physics and such understanding. It uses the basic knowledge about classical Boltzmann statistics. I am not an expert of physical history. If you want to derive that too, you may do so but I don't do it today. Good night.

Comment: No, your derivation is equivalent to the traditional one. Wien's displacement law is much weaker: it does not give a specific result for $\rho_\nu$ but only constrains the form it may take in terms of some unknown function $f$. Finding $f$ means deriving either Wien's distribution law or the full Planck law, both of which are stronger than the question at hand.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although I was more interested in the historical derivation of the weak version of the function as I wrote it in the question. Just the way Wien derived it from maxwell's electromagnetism and classical thermodynamics.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty: What would be $f$ in your understanding? One has to assume of course also a force free and isotropic system for Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution too. It is derived from Boltzmann transport equation as you might know or see http://www.itp.phys.ethz.ch/education/lectures_hs12/StatPhys/Notes-SP-HS12-complete.pdf at chapter 2.4.