# What is the distance between photons?

Tags: thermodynamics, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, thermal-radiation, wavelength

In the book of *The First Three Minutes* by Weinberg, at page 69, he states that

> We also saw that the decrease in the energy density of black-body
>   radiation at long wavelengths is due to the diffi- culty of putting
>   radiation in any volume whose dimensions are smaller than a
>   wavelength. In fact, the average distance between photons in
>   black-body radiation is roughly equal to the typical photon wavelength

However, how can we talk about "the distance between photons" ? What is the author referring to ? and what is the physical explanation of his claim ?

Comment: Looks like he is trying to say that two photons can be distinguished as separate photons if they are separated by atleast a factor of their Compton wavelength.

Comment: @YuzurihaInori But this is wrong, right ? I mean I have seen some posts related with this, but they suggest that two photon can even occupy the same place because they are bosons, see https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/distance-between-photons.390829/

Comment: They try to occupy the same *quantum state* because of something called the *Bose-Einstein Statistics* that has to do with their quantum spins. It's not a *physical place* in the sense of classical intuition.

Comment: @YuzurihaInori I see. So continuing from your first comment: Then his claim in the quote is just based on his own definition ?

Comment: The definition is actually standard, all physicists actually have this in mind when they do calculations. They just don't state it so explicitly. Weinberg did this in order for the normal public to have an insight in the thinking processes of a physicist. It's his *way* of stating something that physicists take for granted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The average distance between photons can be estimated in the following conceptual way.

First, calculate the energy density of the blackbody radiation field.

Then divide by the average energy of a photon (which is $2.7 k_BT$ - refer to my answer to [In a thermal equilibrium, why do individual photons energy is proportional to the temperature?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/398472/in-a-thermal-equilibrium-why-do-individual-photons-energy-is-proportional-to-th/398523#398523)).

The result is the number density (per unit volume) of photons. The inverse of this gives the volume occupied by one photon and so the cube root of this gives an estimate for the average separation between photons.

More formally:

The energy density of a blackbody radiation field is
$$u_{\nu} = \frac{4\pi}{c} B_{\nu}\ d\nu = \frac{8\pi h \nu^{3}}{c^3} \frac{d\nu}{\exp(h\nu/k_BT) - 1}$$
The number density of photons is therefore
$$ n = \int \frac{u_{\nu}}{h\nu}\ d\nu = \frac{8\pi}{c^3} \int \frac{\nu^2\ d\nu}{\exp(h\nu/k_BT) - 1} $$
This integral needs the help of a set of integral tables or [Wolfram integrator](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20x%5E2%2F(e%5Ex%20-%201)from%20x%3D0%20to%20infinity) to give
$$ n = 8\pi \left(\frac{k_BT}{hc}\right)^3 \times 2.404 $$

But from [Wien's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien%27s_displacement_law) we know that a "typical" photon wavelength (well, the wavelength of a photon at the peak of the Planck distribution) has
$$\lambda_{\rm Wien} = \frac{2.9\times 10^{-3}}{T}$$

Putting these together we can express number density in terms of the Wien wavelength, rather than temperature, as
$$ n = 8\pi (\frac{0.20}{\lambda_{\rm Wien}})^3 \times 2.404$$
Taking the inverse cube root we finally arrive at a typical photon separation of
$$ l_{\rm photon} \simeq 1.27 \lambda_{\rm Wien}$$