# Deriving Wien's approximation

Tags: temperature, thermal-radiation, wavelength

Without Planck's law from where and how could one empirically get this.

Could it be got from power is proportional to fourth power of temperature.

Comment: Related (may be duplicate) question: [Historic derivation of Wien's law](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/54342/historic-derivation-of-wiens-law)

Comment: Was it empirical first and then thermodynamics was used...

Comment: Yes it is a duplicate, but i still want to know how could such a complex form be empirically got

Comment: What was yoir search term to get that post, before asking i already searched but got no such results

Comment: The crazy part is even after typing the title historic derivation of wein's law there is no such post visible, is it shadowed

Comment: it is Wien, not Wein.